# Can I insert <header> inside <form> element?

Tags: html, forms

From [example](https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/html/forms/html-form-structure/payment-form.html) on MDN, I learned that I could title a form with heading tags like this:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <h1>Payment form</h1>
  <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
  <!--Input fields-->
</form>
```

My question: is it valid insert these *introductory* information (the title`<h1>` and the `<p>`) inside a `<header>` tag like this:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <header>
    <h1>Payment form</h1>
    <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
  </header>
  <!--Input fields-->
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? Is it valid? Ask a validator. Is it semantically sound? Absolutely.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. I was asking if it was valid. Is my question valid on Stack? :'D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is valid. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-form-element that states that the **form** element can contain any ***Flow content*** except another form.

> 4.10.3. **The form element**
>   Categories: Flow content. Palpable content.
>   Contexts in which this element can be used: Where flow content is expected.
>   **Content model: Flow content** , but with no form element descendants.

And in certain situations it **can** be semantically correct too. In my opinion, only when you need to semantically group various elements as an introduction to the form. For just a heading and a paragraph, ask yourself if grouping them **means** something or it's just information that complements the form itself.

Answer (score -5):

No. headers are not meant to handle forms.
so they should be separation from each other